# Multiple TextView and single OnTouch event listener

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener

I have a simple task - character quick search - http://prntscr.com/7m10fu
I did it as 26 TextViews each of it has OnClickListener that scroll main contact list to appropriate letter. Now I want that it work as in iOS. 
When user press some letter and move it cross all other - contacts scrolls according to letter that finger cross.

I tried to make onTouchListener like this

```
 tvE.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
 tvF.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
 tvG.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

 View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            lastPressedView = -1;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            lastPressedView = v.getId();
            Log.v("w201","Down - "+lastPressedView);
            onQuickClick(v);
            return false;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.v("w201","Move: "+lastPressedView+" | "+ v.getId());
            if (lastPressedView != v.getId()) {
                lastPressedView = v.getId();

                onQuickClick(v);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

But it's doesn't work. v.getId() return always ID of TextView where ACTION_DOWN triggered. After that all ACTION_MOVE triggered for this View.

So two questions:

1. How to make correct OnTouchListener that it work like next: User press on letter A, ACTION_DOWN triggered for TextView A, after that user swipe finger to TextView B and move event triggered for TextView B & so on.
2. Maybe some one can help to make quick letter search better then I did it.

Thanks.

Comment: why not select contacts that are like entered pattern? just like any autocomplete does?

Answer (score 0):

Use AlphaIndexer and SectionIndex and your work is done. Just google for them. There is no need for you to create custom listeners.

Comment: as I understand AlphaIndexer & SectionIndex doesn't show right side bar with letter. I haven't any problem with find section in listView and scroll listview to this position. I have a problem with right side bar and situation when user not just click to letter, but click and move finger to other letters.